# Preview with Eclipse Web Page Editor and AngularJS not working

Tags: angularjs, eclipse

I'm currently trying to get the preview functionality from the Eclipse Web Page Editor with AngularJS up and running. Unfortunately nothing happens (see attached image) when I try to run the provided code.
It seems to run [here](http://blog.diniscruz.com/2014/02/using-angularjs-in-eclipse-part-1.html).

The code runs in every web browser - so the question is why is it not working in the "Preview Tab" of the Eclipse Web Page Editor? Any ideas?

My Setup:

- Eclipse Mars.1 Release (4.5.1) for Web Developers
- AngularJS Eclipse 1.1

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <title>Insert title here</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div>
   <label>Name:</label> 
   <input type="text" ng-model="yourName" placeholder="Enter a name here">
   <hr>
   <h1>Hello {{yourName}}!</h1>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ARjx.jpg)